# interpretation of coefficients of independent variables in fractions

Tags: regression-coefficients, linear

I am a bachelor student finishing my thesis and desperately need some help with the interpretation of regression coefficients. I am currently quite confused and my deadline is three days away. I have two models estimated using linear regression.

Model 1:  Y = β0 + β1 X1 + β2 log(X2)

Variables Y and X1 are in fraction ranging from 0 to 1. X2 is a continuous variable and in log form.

Model 2:  log(Z) = α0 + α1 X3

Variable Z is a continuous variable and in log form. X3 are in fraction ranging from 0 to 1.

I want to calculate the percentage change in the dependent variables with respect to a 10% increase in the relevant independent variable. This is because my supervisor wanted me to report the economic significance of the coefficients. If we assume the following values, how much change in Y and log(Z) takes place?

β1 = 0.07 
β2 = 0.042
α1 = 0.65

Comment: This document will help you: https://kenbenoit.net/assets/courses/ME104/logmodels2.pdf.

Comment: @Isabella Ghement Thank you for your suggestion. It was very helpful and solved my problem.